# Composite literal uses unkeyed fields when referencing type but not in defining package

Tags: go

I have two packages, `db` and `service`. In `db`, I take in a type created by protobuf and wrap it with another type, like so:

```
type BatchStatus struct {
    gopb.BatchInvoiceStatus
}
```

When I want to create one of these objects, I can do so like this:

```
status := BatchStatus{
    gopb.BatchInvoiceStatus{
        Id:            makeBatchStatusID(mspID, period),
        SortKey:       makeBatchStatusSortKey(mspID, uuid),
        InvoiceStatus: Preparing,
        InvoiceType:   batchType,
        Start:         start,
        Count:         0,
    },
}
```

This does not present an error, as I would expect. However, if I try to do the same thing in the `services` package:

```
status := &db.BatchStatus{
    gopb.BatchInvoiceStatus{
        Id:            makeBatchStatusID(mspID, period),
        SortKey:       makeBatchStatusSortKey(mspID, uuid),
        InvoiceStatus: Preparing,
        InvoiceType:   batchType,
        Start:         start,
        Count:         0,
    },
}
```

I get a warning stating that `db.BatchStatus composite literal uses unkeyed fields`. Why does this warning not occur in the package where `BatchStatus` is defined but does occur when referenced outside the package?

Comment: From the docs for that analysis: "This analyzer reports a diagnostic for composite literals of struct types imported from _another package_ that do not use the field-keyed syntax."

Comment: @JimB Okay, so it's in the analyzer documentation, but why did they make that decision? It doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Because it's useful, and you have control over the type so you shouldn't be surprised by changes in the structure.

Comment: @JimB Are you implying that I wouldn't see this warning if I was using a type from an external package?

Comment: No, you only get the warning when the type is from another package, as you've demonstrated above.

Comment: @JimB You mean if the inner type is from another package, yes? I don't see the warning if the inner and outer types are from the same package.